# Terraform Map of List input variables-For_each

Tags: foreach, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to implement for_each for map of list input variables.

What the output should be is a list of subnets should be created for AZ us-east-1a(3 subnets) and us-east-1b (2 subnets).

Need your help for the below:

MAIN.TF

```
resource "aws_vpc" "name" {
  cidr_block = "192.168.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "name" {
  for_each = var.subnetcidr
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.name.id
  availability_zone = each.key
  cidr_block = toset(each.value) //need help here
}
```

TFVARS FILE

```
subnetcidr = {
  "us-east-1a" = ["192.168.1.0/24","192.168.2.0/24","192.168.0.0/24"]
  "us-east-1b" = ["192.168.3.0/24","192.168.4.0/24"]
}
```

Error:

```text
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on main.tf line 28, in resource "aws_subnet" "name":
  28:   cidr_block = toset(each.value)
    |----------------
    | each.value is tuple with 2 elements

Inappropriate value for attribute "cidr_block": string required.
```

Any help would be appreciated. TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this. Below is how.

resource "aws_vpc" "name" {

cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"

}

resource "aws_subnet" "name" {

vpc_id = aws_vpc.name.id

for_each = transpose(var.subnet)

availability_zone = each.value[0]

cidr_block = each.key

}

variable subnet {}

subnet = {

"us-east-1a" = ["10.0.0.0/20","10.0.16.0/20","10.0.32.0/20"]

"us-east-1b" =
["10.0.64.0/20","10.0.80.0/20"]

"us-east-1d" = ["10.0.112.0/20","10.0.128.0/20","10.0.144.0/20","10.0.96.0/20"]

}

Answer (score 0):

The error seems clear:
`Inappropriate value for attribute "cidr_block": string required`
Not sure why you are passing a list...

---

#### If you need to keep it as a list, an option could be getting the first value:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "name" {
  cidr_block = "192.168.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "name" {
  for_each = var.subnetcidr
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.name.id
  availability_zone = each.key
  cidr_block = element(each.value, 0)
}
```

---

#### If you can change the `subnetcidr` variable, go with something like:

```
subnetcidr = {  
  "192.168.0.0/24" = "us-east-1a"
  "192.168.1.0/24" = "us-east-1a"
  "192.168.2.0/24" = "us-east-1a"

  "192.168.3.0/24" = "us-east-1b"
  "192.168.4.0/24" = "us-east-1b"
}
```

As you can see now the unique cidr blocks are the keys and the zones are the values.
Then in your code we do like this:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "name" {
  cidr_block = "192.168.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "name" {
  for_each = var.subnetcidr
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.name.id
  availability_zone = each.value
  cidr_block = each.key
}
```

Comment: Thanks Helder for the answer.

Comment: Thanks Helder for the answer.
1. I know the value should be string, but I need to pass in list and then it should take 1 by 1 values.
2. element(each.value,0) we should not use because it should be automatic.
3. I can check with the option 3 that you have told. 

Thank you

Comment: @prakashjha, yes from your comment it seems the only option is to change the `subnetcidr` variable ... you just can not pass a list and expect it will take it 1 by 1 values, that is just not how the `resource "aws_subnet"` works

Comment: Yes, in a way, for_each and list both cant be used right?

Comment: @prakashjha I want to make sure I do not mislead you ... In theory, they can both work fine ... for_each and list of values can be used for resources that accept a list in arguments, ... but that is not the case with `aws_subnet` and its argument `cidr_block` ... consult the terraform-provider-aws documentation for details

Comment: Hi Helder, thanks for the help. I was finally able to get through this. Below is how.

resource "aws_vpc" "name" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "name" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.name.id
  for_each = transpose(var.subnet)
  availability_zone = each.value[0]
  cidr_block = each.key
}

variable subnet {}

subnet = {
  "us-east-1a" = ["10.0.0.0/20","10.0.16.0/20","10.0.32.0/20"]
"us-east-1b" = ["10.0.64.0/20","10.0.80.0/20"]
"us-east-1d" = ["10.0.112.0/20","10.0.128.0/20","10.0.144.0/20","10.0.96.0/20"]
}

Comment: @prakshjha you should post that as an answer